# How to create live stream audio for web-sites?

Tags: java, web, audio-streaming

We are storing sound from mic to pc via sound forge.

We would like to broadcast the sound which comes from the mic to the pc as live streaming audio.

Basically a person speaks in a mic, we like to give it as live stream audio.

The web-site is hosted on yahoo server.

Can you please let me know in what are the ways we can achieve this?

Thanks,
Kathir

Comment: Does Yahoo server supports java? I think No, please check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can rent shoutcast/icecast2 stream from a lot of shoutcast/icecast2 stream hosters.
Then just embed flash based player with this stream in your site page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SSH access to server? You can install shoutcast server(http://www.shoutcast.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But unfortunately Yahoo web hosting server doesn't support SSH as of now. Can you please let me know some other ways ???

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this issue but you will need a Shoutcast or Icecast server to do this. It can be complicated if you aren't familiar with operating a server. It's easier to rent space on a Shoutcast server. You can find a great service which is affordable at [MyRadiHosting](https://myradiohosting.com).

You would want to put a player code in your website that works across all browsers and devices. We use the one below and have had no issues.

```
<audio src="http://YOUR IP ADDRESS:YOUR PORT/;" id="MediaPlayer1" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
```

Hope this answer helps!